# How to open a webpage within a gtk# desktop application?

Tags: c#, html, gtk#

I need to open a webpage I created in php, in my C # application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example **using C#**, I hope this can help you.

If you want to open a link in your default browser, you can add this simple code:

```
Process.Start("http://YourURL");
```

---

If you want to open your link in another browser, you can use this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://YourURL");
```

---

And you can visit these posts:

- [How do I open alternative webbrowser (Mozilla or Firefox) and show the specific url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223268/771579)
- [.NET C#: WebBrowser control Navigate() does not load targeted URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2747379/771579)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want it to open inside of my GTK Gui